# Redirect to an external URL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm developing a web application using angularJS but only the authentication page doesn't use angularJS, it uses simply html .

So when the user is disconnected it must redirect him to authentication page,so I made an interceptor that executed before any request and use a service from my application to validate if the user is connected , if he's not he must be redirected to the authentication page .

This my interceptor code :

```
                $httpProvider.interceptors
                        .push(function($q, $injector) {
                            return {
                                'request' : function(request) {
                                        var $http = $injector.get('$http');
/*
calls service from my application to verify the if the user is connected
*/
                                        $http
                                                .get("sessionValidator")
                                                .success(
                                                        function(data) {
                                                            if (data.result == 'sessionNull'
                                                                    || data.role != 'ROLE_USER') {
                                                                window.location.href = '/authenticationPage';
                                                            } 

                                                        });
return request;
                                },
                            };
                        });
```

My problem is there is a loop generated when I call the service(because it's another request and the interceptor will be executed again).Any solutions for my problem or is there another way to do this.

Comment: Such interceptor are written over response rather than request. You can write a response interceptor and check the status returned by `sessionValidator`. If it has error just redirect.

Comment: This should really be in a controller, you should create a service which checks the user role, then redirects the user if no role is found. Then, inject the service into every controller that would use this check. This should not be in a interceptor.

Comment: @Chandermani thanks for the reply but I think it's not the good one because I have to check user's role so it's not enough to check only response's status, and where can I make the call of the service if it's not made in request interceptor?

Comment: @EliteOctagon thanks,but do you think it's the optimal solution to try, because I have to write the same code in each contoller ?

Comment: Interceptors can take dependencies, which means you can check anything in you interceptor as long there is a service doing it.

Comment: @OmarZRIDI see my answer below, this way you do not have to write repetitive code in each controller, just inject it into each controller/service which uses $http. Also, you have a central service which runs your http calls, intercepts the request, intercepts the response, and allows you to do any pre-processing on the response if you wish to. You can even rename the service to something simpler, like 'myHttp' rather than the long name I gave it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your description and your comments you could set up a service which intercepts both the request and the response. I created a generic one, see code below with example plunker. You can expand that code quite a bit to achieve what you want.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.service("interceptorService", function($http, $q) {

  // this service only has post and get, but post I documented get
  return {

    get: function(url, parameters){
      var deferred = $q.defer(); // the promise which we will return

      $http.get(url, {params: parameters}).then(function(successResponse){

        // check for null session or role being not a user, and redirect if response is approved
        if (successResponse.data.result == 'sessionNull' || successResponse.data.role != 'ROLE_USER'){
          window.location.href = '/authenticationPage';

          // this should probably be rejected because you don't want to process the response if the person is not a user, also the person is being redirected anyways
          deferred.reject(successResponse);
        } else{
          // since this is successful, we can resolve this successfully
          deferred.resolve(successResponse);
        }

      }, function(failureResponse){

        console.log(failureResponse);
        deferred.reject(failureResponse);


      });
      return deferred.promise;

    },
    post: function(url, parameters){
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      $http.post(url, parameters).then(function(successResponse){
        console.log(successResponse);
        deferred.resolve(successResponse);
      }, function(failureResponse){
        console.log(failureResponse);
        deferred.reject(failureResponse);
      });
      return deferred.promise;

    }
  }
})

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'interceptorService', function($scope, interceptorService){

  var url = 'http://api.sba.gov/geodata/city_county_links_for_state_of/tx.xml';
  interceptorService.get(url).then(function(response){
    $scope.result = "http call succeeded";
  }, function(reason){
    $scope.result = "http call failed";
  });

}]);
```